# JENKINS Authentication Fails

Tags: rest, curl, jenkins, postman

I am getting the following error while trying to trigger Jenkins job from any REST Client

> ```
> Authentication required
>
>      <!-- You are authenticated as: anonymous
> Groups that you are in:
>
> Permission you need to have (but didn't):
> hudson.model.Hudson.Read
> ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
> ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
> -->
>     </body> </html>
> ```

The request is getting triggered while using curl from terminal

I am using the following syntax

http://user:apiToken@jenkins.yourcompany.com/job/your_job/build?token=TOKEN 
  [ref :https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients]

ie. curl -X POST http://user:apiToken@jenkins.yourcompany.com/job/your_job/build?token=TOKEN

Comment: I'm using the same scheme and it's working for me in the browser: user:ApiToken@domain.com/job/my_job/build?token=TOKEN

Answer (score 12):

Check this "This build is parameterized " , select the credentials parameter from drop down.
Use this

```
curl -X POST http://jenkins.rtcamp.com/job/Snapbox/buildWithParameters --user "username:password"
```

It solved my authentication problem.

I hope it will help others too.

Answer (score 6):

My development team's configuration settings were `matrix-based security` so I had to find my group and give my group workspace access.

```
1.Click on Manage Jenkins .   
2.Click on Configure Global Security .  
3.in matrix-based security change: 

Overall - Read   
Job - Build  
Job - Read   
Job - Workspace
```

Then

```
    POST jobUrl/buildWithParameters HTTP/1.1
    Host: user:token
    Authorization: Basic dWdlbmxpazo4elhjdmJuTQ==
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

    Branch=develop
```

Answer (score 5):

For me

https://user:password@jenkins.mycompany.org/job/job_name/build?token=my_token

in https://jenkins.mycompany.org/configureSecurity

disable CORS

hope this help

Answer (score 2):

Try using the -u parameter to specify the credentials:

`curl -u user:apiToken -X POST http://jenkins.yourcompany.com/job/your_job/build?token=TOKEN`

Comment: This does work with curl. But I am trying to trigger the same job from POSTMAN REST client and it fails with authentication required.

Comment: If it works with curl you're obviously having a specific problem with the postman client parameters.  Sorry that I don't know anything about that, but at least it narrows down the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I provided header Authorization parameter with value :
BASIC base_64encoded(username:password) and it worked fine.

Authorization    Basic bmltbWljdjpqZX*********

Comment: worked for me too. if you need a Base64 encoder, check https://www.base64encode.org/

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against using a base64encode.org for your credentials because it sends its input to the server.  Many systems will have a base64 command that you can use like `echo -n 'test:testpass' | base64`

Answer (score 1):

Simply disable "CSRF Protection" in the global Security Options, because those URLs don't send post data identification.

Answer (score 0):

focal point ：
**username:password@**

```
curl -u user:apiToken -X POST http://username:password@jenkins.yourcompany.com/job/your_job/build?key1=value1&key2=value2 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are encountering this problem with jenkins api client in ruby.
I figured Jenkins is blocking all the get request, instead use api_post_request.
Also, you have to generate api token because normal password is not working anymore.

```
@client = JenkinsApi::Client.new(
    server_url: "",
    username: '',
    password: ""
)
SITE_FILE_PATH = 'artifact/target/site'.freeze
@jenkins_uri=''
@jenkins_job_name=''

def latest_test_file_path
    "/job/#{@jenkins_job_name}/job/master/lastSuccessfulBuild/#{SITE_FILE_PATH}/Test-Results/test-results.html"
end

puts @client.api_post_request(latest_test_file_path,{},true).body
```

you can set the parameter true if you want the raw response.
default parameter or passing false will just return response code.

Also make sure to construct the right prefix.
You can refer to the above snipped.